# Копирование read-only файлов

Tags: c++, winapi

### Суть проблемы:

При копировании файла в каталог, где уже существует файл с таким же именем и с атрибутом ReadOnly, функция копирования CopyFile возвращает FALSE. Одним из решений является снятие атрибута RO с целевого файла и повторная попытка копии, что существенно тормозит процесс при копировании больших объемов мелких файлов (100к+). Существуют ли методы позволяющие в 1 действие скопировать ro-файл в другой ro-файл?

### Код:

```
CString sFrom = _T("D:\test1\test.log");
CString sTo   = _T("D:\test2\test.log"); // Этот файл должен быть read-only

BOOL bRet = CopyFile(sFrom, sTo, FALSE);

if ( FALSE == bRet )
{
    DWORD dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(sTo);
    dwAttr &= ~FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY;
    SetFileAttributes(sTo, dwAttr);
    bRet = CopyFile(sFrom, sTo, FALSE);
}

return bRet;
```

Comment: Тут хорошо бы `GetLastError()` проверить при ошибке

Comment: `system("xcopy /r /y src dst");`

Comment: @alexolut, спс, пока нет возможности протестить на большом объеме файлов, но думаю сойдет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним действием такого не сделаешь. Атрибуты придуманы для защиты от ошибочных или вредоносных действий, поэтому все операции с ними должны выполняться явно. Если файлу установлен признак "только для чтения", то видимо в этом есть смысл. Подумайте, может вы что-то делаете не правильно.